# javascript in 200 ok http response

Tags: javascript, http, servlets

I have two javascript file ie 1.js and 2.js. Both files are having 1000 lines of javascript code.

I need to include these js in the 200 OK HTTP successful response.

Please give me some pointers to do it.

Addition :

After the user logs in to portal there will be multiple Java scripts needs to be executed in the UI plugin. Secondly this should be executed periodically based on the Mousedown, Mousemove,Scroll etc events

Comment: <script src="1.js"></script>

Comment: I really don't understand your question...

Comment: "incomplete / overly broad".  Please submit your question again with details details details about what tech you're basing it on, what you want, and WHAT YOU HAVE TRIED.

Comment: @ Alexandre Lavoie : After the user logs in to portal there will be multiple Java scripts needs to be executed in the UI plugin. Secondly this should be executed periodically based on the Mousedown,
Mousemove,Scroll etc events..I am using java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, this is what we understand really.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src='1.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='2.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

This gives you a HTTP Response of 200 !

Comment: Thanks.,,now these Java scripts needs to be executed in the UI plugin based on the Mousemove,Scroll events...how these js will get executed

Comment: @VJS, Your UI Plugin is Mr.Browser right ?

Comment: yes, that will be browser.

Comment: @VJS, You need to define those functions (mouseMove, mouseOver) etc in the Javascript file (1.js or 2.js) and then you need to call those functions to your input button or checkbox in your form. There are events like onClick , onMouseOver , so just map these events to your functions which you have defined in your javascript files.